# What happen If we set both "added site to Compatibility View Settings in IE" and "<meta HTTP-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> "

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

When both compatibility view settings enabled for the site and meta tag with IE version mentioned, with what version the site is going to render?

I have added the site of my page, to compatibility view settings of IE11 browser.
And in that page, we do have

```
<meta HTTP-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Will the IE forced to render the page in quirks mode? (As I added the site to compatibility view settings, browser forced to render the page with IE5 mode as per my knowledge).

Does the browser mode change to IE11(as I set mode as "IE=Edge")?

Please clarify!!!

Comment: You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do) to know more about this meta tag.